# Algorithms for biased spawning of items

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, real-time

In my game, I would like to spawn N items, not necessarily at the same time. Some of the items are dependent on what was spawned before (Markov chain-esque), so the probability of spawning two rocket launchers in a row is low, but there's a reasonable probability of spawning a rocket launcher followed by rockets. What would be the most efficient way of doing this? The method will be called very often, so I'm trying to keep calculations to a minimum.

An idea I came up with could be to create an N x N array which acts as a lookup table of the probabilities (Item previously spawned VS Item to spawn). However, in this process, I would need some way of generating a random number with the probability acting as a bias. I am not sure what the best way of doing that is. Things also get slightly tricker when an inventory comes into play, as rockets cannot be generated if Y amount have already spawned. I could create a 3D array and store the inventory number in there, but I'm not sure how efficient it would be to keep updating an array lookup table based on inventory.

That's just an idea I came up with, but there's probably another, better, way of doing this. Are there any data structures that would be more efficient than a 3D array, or algorithms I should read up on?

Comment: It's a bit general.. what have you tried?..  If I had all of the details I'm sure I could write something, but as of now I don't know what to say.

Comment: Hi, I'm still in design stage and trying to work out the theory of it first. Is there something you'd like me to explain further?

Comment: I'm skeptical that this process will be a bottleneck.  I'd implement something simple without worrying about efficiency, first.

Comment: Optimisation isn't key at the moment, but I was wondering if there were any algorithms currently used that do something similar. I didn't want to be barking up the wrong tree with 3D arrays, if other structures were more commonly used for this type of problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way, if you don't need much state stored, is to do just what you hinted: create a Markov chain.  Associated with each state is an array of probabilities of exit to the next state.  This gives you complete control over the process and is pretty compact.  (Note that you use it by generating a random number from 0 to 1 and doing a binary search on the cumulative probabililties.)

An alternative, fuzzier approach is to maintain a set of probabilities and a set of biases.  If you have a bias term like

```
launcher_bias = 0.8*launcher_bias + 0.2*(1.0 - (last_item == launcher))
rocket_bias = 0.8*rocket_bias + 0.2*(last_item == launcher)
```

and you weight your probabilities with these values (and then renormalize the whole set to 1, or equivalently if the total probability of all items ends up at 0.7 or somesuch, you pick values from 0 to 0.7) you will find that as you get excess launchers the probability of getting more will drop.  But, at the same time, you'll increase the chance of getting rockets.  Basically, you'll have some exponentially decaying weighting factor that prejudices you against launchers if you've had one recently.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I should read a bit more into Markov models. What do you mean by doing a binary search on the cumulatitive properties to use the chain?

Comment: Suppose you have probabilities `0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1`, in that order, for five different outcomes. You convert that into the array `0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0`. If you pick a random number from 0 to 1 then the chance you fall between 0 and 0.2 is 0.2; between 0.2 and 0.7 is 0.5, and so on.  Pick a random number and do a binary search, looking for which range you fall in and thus which outcome to pick. If you have more than a half dozen or so different possibilities, and you need to do this fast, it'll be faster than Tom's method. (Divide Tom's numbers by 4+1+1+10 to get probabilities....)

Comment: Of course, if you have relatively few items, a binary search may not be any faster (or with more items, noticeably faster) than a simple linear search.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm trying to make the engine quite versatile, so a binary search would be an option.

Answer (score 3):

> However, in this process, I would need
>   some way of generating a random number
>   with the probability acting as a bias.
>   Not sure what the best way of doing
>   that is?

Say you have 4 events

- event A, relative probability: 4
- event B, relative probability: 1
- event C, relative probability: 1
- event D, relative probability: 10

The sum of relative probabilities is 16, so generate a random number **X** in the range [0,16).  Four of those numbers should map to A, one to B, etc.

- subtract 4 from **X**.  If **X** is now negative, pick event A.
- else, subtract 1 from **X**.  If **X** is now negative, pick event B.
- else, subtract 1 from **X**.  If **X** is now negative, pick event C.
- else, Pick event D.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great method!